# How to insert a Javascript object to a Postgres table?

Tags: json, python-3.x, postgresql, dictionary, psycopg2

So i have a python script that returns objects like the following example:

```
{'new': False,
 'code': 5023,
 'id': '5d4ea268e92b451600854af0',
 'photos': [{'id': 'ccd3663d-bf42-4ae1-12ec-2fd5a9e2dd19',
   'crop_info': {'user': {'width_pct': 1.0,
     'x_offset_pct': 0.0,
     'height_pct': 1.0,
     'y_offset_pct': 0.0},
    'algo': {'width_pct': 0.07293634116649628,
     'x_offset_pct': 0.5088474750518799,
     'height_pct': 0.1020476222038269,
     'y_offset_pct': 0.17648863792419434},
   'url': 'https://photos.cars.com/1.jpeg',
   'processedFiles': [{'url': 'https://photos.cars.com/1x.jpg',
     'height': 640,
     'width': 640},
    {'url': 'https://photos.cars.com/1x_2.jpg',
     'height': 320,
     'width': 320},
    {'url': 'https://photos.cars.com/1x_3.jpg',
     'height': 172,
     'width': 172},
    {'url': 'https://photos.cars.com/1x_4.jpg',
     'height': 84,
     'width': 84}],
   'last_update_time': '2019-07-29T07:33:43.509Z',
   'fileName': '1x.webp',
   'extension': 'jpg,webp',
   'webp_qf': [75]}],
 'self_car': {'is_car': True,
  'car_pos': {'lat': 31.230416, 'lon': 121.473701},
  'car_location_info': [{'country': {'long_name': 'China',
     'short_name': 'CN'},
    'locality': {'long_name': 'Shanghai', 'short_name': 'Shanghai'},
    'lat': 31.230029,
    'lon': 121.473945}]}}
```

> type(example) returns a dictionary.

I need to store many of these objects in a Postgres table. Ideally i want the keys to fit column names, but only for first level keys. (e.g. i want 'car_location_info' as a column but not 'locality')

I created the table using:

> CREATE TABLE "test" ("new" text, "code" text, ...) #All are text

I have tried various ways with no luck. e.g. i tried:

```py
cur = connection.cursor()
keys = example.keys()
columns = ','.join(keys)
values = ','.join(['%({})s'.format(k) for k in keys])
insert = 'insert into table ({0}) values ({1})'.format(columns, values)
print(cur.mogrify(insert, example))
```

I keep running into ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'dict.

Comment: How about parsing to json and insert the json object?

Comment: @Iñigo How would you go on about that? json.dumps(example) create a string. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create a JSON column type in postgres and use psycopg2 to insert the json dumped as a string

`import psycopg2;
import json;
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="postgres", user="postgres", host="127.0.0.1", port="54320");
cursor = conn.cursor();
my_dict = {"hello":"there","my":{"name":{"is":"shmuel"}}};
cursor.execute("insert into test2 (json_data) values (%s)",[json.dumps(my_dict)]);
conn.commit();
cursor.close();
`